# JPA/Ebean - force @Id to strictly increment by +1 with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, ebean

I have the following Model:

```
public class Parameter extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;
}
```

The records created by `save()` look like this:

```
play=> select id from parameter;
 id
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
 21
(6 rows)
```

Is there a way that I can tell JPA to always increment the `id` by exactly one, instead of randomly jumping to 21?

Comment: In short - there is no way to do that. Id fields are only guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are observing (jump to 21) is likely to be an implmentation detail of Ebean prior to 4.0.5. Ebean is using a 'fetch ahead' mechanism on the sequence. After 4.0.5 Ebean switched to use Postgres SERIAL by default (so by default you won't see this with Ebean/Postgres after 4.0.5). Refer: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/97

That all said - 'incrementing EXACTLY by 1' is something you generally want to avoid as it becomes a concurrency issue (avoid making the autoincrement ID transactional as that introduces contention).  When you need 'increment exactly by one' semantics (like cheque numbers etc) then you can look to create in batch in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure all IDs are larger than any previous IDs? That would be fine as well.

Comment: @doque In terms of Ebean it is using the underlying DB sequences (or DB autoincrement depending on the DB) so *generally* yes you will observe that the ID's allocated are larger than any previous IDs *HOWEVER* that strictly doesn't have to be the case and might not strictly be the case with Oracle RAC (or other similarly clustered DB's where blocks of ids are allocated across DB nodes). You can check the docs/behaviour on your underlying database but you might consider it safer/better to add a 'when created' Timestamp column (with Ebean you'd use @CreateTimestamp).

Comment: Summary: DB sequences (and autoincrement) will be unique, may have gaps, are generally but not strictly incrementing (depends on DB implementation so for example DB clustering like Oracle RAC), often good to add an additional 'whenCreated' timestamp column to help to provide query ordering when you can not or do not want to rely on 'IDs are strictly incrementing'.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by using `@TableGenerator` and `allocationSize=1`. An example code something like the following. You need to create a separate table to store the PK, additional work, but more portable than `@GeneratedValue`.

```
@TableGenerator(name="MAIN_PK_GEN", table="pk_gen", pkColumnName="GEN_NAME", valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE", pkColumnValue="MAIN_PK_GEN", allocationSize=1)
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="MAIN_PK_GEN" )
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PK")
    private Integer pk;
```

(But using `allocationSize=1` may not be efficient)

See [this tutorial](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/14/automatic-id-creation-using-jpa-table-generator/) for step by step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle don't forget to add **SequenceGenerator** with an allocationSize of 1 :

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mysequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mysequence", sequenceName = "mysequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
```